# Dynamic color change not work in three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created wall in three JS. I try to change the color dynamically on click event. But its not work. What is the error in below code:

```
var materials = [ materialFront, materialSide ];

var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );

if(path_type=="wall")
{
    var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry1, material );
    object.add( mesh1 );
}
else {
    var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry1, material );
    object.add( mesh2 );
}

object.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
object.position.y = parseInt(default_height*(floor_number-1));  
scene.add( object );
```

Onclick change color code:

```
function color_change(color){ 
 mesh1.material.color = new THREE.Color( color );         
 mesh1.material.needsUpdate = true;
}
```

I get this error:

> mesh1 not defined

Answer (score 0):

```
if(path_type=="wall")
{
    var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry1, material );
    object.add( mesh1 );
}
```

The variable `mesh1` is declared in the `if` scope, it can not be accessed from outside of that scope. You need to declare it in global scope to access it from other functions.like this -

```
var mesh1;
if(path_type=="wall")
{
    mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry1, material );
    object.add( mesh1 );
}
```

Comment: still error occuring  
ReferenceError: mesh1 is not defined

mesh1.material.color = new THREE.Color( color );

Comment: I think you didn't declare the variable in global scope. For say, you have to declare the variable in the same scope of `scene`. You can declare the variable after you have declared `var scene;`.

Comment: i have declared all in global variable, But its not work, Can you share your email id, i will send my entire code, can you help?

Comment: Thanks I got result, Thanks for inter friend